# Coin flipping game probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a 2 sided fair penny, if I flip heads 4 times in a row I win 10 dollars but it costs 1 dollar to play, should I play the game?

Is the answer no because $(10/2^4)-1$ is negative?

Comment: you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your win/lose analysis goes like this:

**Win** probability is `(0.5)^4` and you'll have $10

**Lose** probability is `1-(0.5)^4` and it costs you $4

So your expected value goes like this:

```
(10*0.0625) + (-4*0.9375) = -3.125
```

To put it in plain English, you will lose, on average, `$3.125` for every `$4` you will invest so if you came with a `$400` to play 100 games, you will likely to leave with `$87.5`.